# How to start multiple virtual machines simultaneously in CloudStack

Tags: apache-cloudstack

Is there a way to start multiple virtual machines (instances) simultaneously in CloudStack?

Apparently this can't be done using the http user interface. Also, the http API request specifies only one id for targeting the virtual machine.

All I can think to solve this problem is to fire multiple individual start requests for each instance, then polling each of the job for results. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

CloudStack is an API driven system, if there is no API call where you can specify multiple VMs to be created (and I don't think there is), then it is not possible.

If you do need to create multiple machines (nearly) simultaneously, the only option I see is to fire multiple API calls, as you already mentioned.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257849/how-to-connect-to-cloudstack-on-java-platform/22096770#22096770) on another question for a list of tools that make interfacing with CloudStack easier.

Answer (score 0):

To start VM on cloudstack simultaneously tho in serial, I used cloudmonkey and created a bash script to setup a group of know VM UUID. See here for my experience
https://sites.google.com/site/cloudfyp/tutorial/cloudmonkey/commands-on-cloudmonkey